# Summing each pair of tuples which returned by the a csv file

Tags: python, csv

Part A: I have been asked to read the data from a csv file which contains 2 columns, and return the data in a tuple.

Part B: And using the data returned from csv file, I needed to sum each pair of tuple:

from part A:

```
def csvReader(filename): #Function for reading .csv file
     with open(filename) as file:

          reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
          next(reader, None)

          data = [tuple(row) for row in reader]
     return(data) 

csvReader('data.csv')
```

Here is what I have returned from part A:

[('60,', '20,'), ('100,', '55,'), ('50,', '40,'), ('20,', '70,'), ('95,', '85,')]

from part B:

```
def Plot(filename):
     return[sum(i) for i in csvReader(filename)] #summing each pair of tuples

Plot('data.csv')
```

I'm expecting something like:

[80, 155, 90, 90, 180]

And I have a type error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: You need to covert the str to int

Comment: Why do you specify `' '` as your delimiter? It seems the file is `','` delimited. Your tuples contain strings (hence the quotation marks), so you'll need to interpret them as integers with `int()`. Note that your choice of delimiter causes commas to be included in the strings, you'll need to exclude those before using `int()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def csvReader(filename): #Function for reading .csv file
     with open(filename) as file:

          reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=' ')
          next(reader, None)

          data = [tuple(map(int, row)) for row in reader]
     return(data) 

csvReader('data.csv')
```

This should help you out. First, convert '60' to 60 ( str to int ) and then other function should work well.

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas to read the csv, and pull our your requirements.

```
a,b
10,20
15,5
30,40
```

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header=0)

df['sum'] = df['a'] + df['b']

tuple_requirement = tuple(zip(df['a'].to_list(), df['b'].to_list()))
sum_requirement = df['sum'].to_list()

print(sum_requirement)
print(tuple_requirement)

# [30, 20, 70]
# ((10, 20), (15, 5), (30, 40))
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than reading CSV then converting the sequences of `str` to a sequence of `int`, you could evaluate the whole file line `str` instead. To safely do this, you can use [**`ast.literal_eval`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('1,2,3,4')
(1,2,3,4)
```

Using it:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    next(f)
    rows = [literal_eval(line) for line in f]

totals = [sum(row) for row in rows]
```